# How to isolate child controller scope from parent controller scope without changing the view?

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-scope, angularjs-controller

Click on the parent button change also child but child button not.
I need to change this behavior isolating scopes whith any hacks or other way.

**Child controller doesn't inherit from parent controller and must have its own scope!**

```js
angular
  .module('app', [])
  .controller('ParentCtrl', function() {})
  .controller('ChildCtrl', function() {})
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.2.23/angular.min.js"></script>
<div ng-app=app>
  <div ng-controller=ParentCtrl>
    <button ng-click="text='clicked'">
      {{text || 'parent'}}
    </button>
    <div ng-controller=ChildCtrl>
      <button ng-click="text='clicked'">
        {{text || 'child'}}
      </button>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

https://jsfiddle.net/nizami/oLwbktz9/

Comment: what exactly do you want?

Comment: I want each controller has its own scope. Child controller doesn't inherit from parent controller

Comment: Thanks! But that's not what I want. I want to use the same name of properties.

Comment: see https://jsfiddle.net/aghosh08/oLwbktz9/4/

Comment: This is not exactly what I need. I cannot change the view.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
angular
  .module('app', [])
  .controller('ParentCtrl', ['$scope', function($scope) {
  $scope.text = null;
  }])
  .controller('ChildCtrl', ['$scope', function($scope) {
  $scope.text = null;
  }])
```

Comment: Is it possible to provide a more complete example, it is not understandable behavior for me?

Comment: This works because of the Prototypical inheritance of javascript. Defining 'text' in the child controller means that angular won't see the parent property of the same name, so now they are effectively separated.

Comment: Thank you very much fo explaining! Yes it is work for me!

Comment: Can i override this logic for all fields or angular logic behavior?

Comment: It's a javascript thing, rather than an Angular thing, so yes, you can override all fields of the parent object this way.

Answer (score 1):

Check the updated plunkr..I hope u will get ur answer

https://jsfiddle.net/oLwbktz9/6/

```
<div ng-controller=ParentCtrl>
  <button ng-click="text='clicked'">
    {{text || 'parent'}}
  </button>
    </div>
  <div ng-controller=ChildCtrl>
    <button ng-click="text='clicked'">
      {{text || 'child'}}
    </button>
</div>
```

Comment: Thanks.  But I cannot change the view. Not so in extreme cases

Comment: You did not want the scopes to be overlapped...right..?

Comment: Yes. I want that all scopes have been isolated from each other

Comment: On clicking on parent it should only change the parent button and on clicking on child only child button value should change....isnt it

Comment: Okkk.....I hope this is not what you are looking for..

https://jsfiddle.net/oLwbktz9/7/

Comment: A change in one field of scope (in parent) does not affect other field (in child)

Comment: Did you look at my previos plunkr

Comment: Yes. At this point by pressing the button of the parent changes child relationship too. But it should not change it

Comment: okk...I think there is some misunderstanding..can you explain me what you want to achieve ..in terms of clicking of buttons

Answer (score 0):

Just change your child controller scope variables. 
Controllers always inherit the scope from the parent controllers.In the directives you have the option of creating isolated scope.

```
<div ng-controller=ParentCtrl>
  <button ng-click="text='clicked'">
    {{text || 'parent'}}
  </button>
  <div ng-controller=ChildCtrl>
    <button ng-click="text2='clicked'">
      {{text2 || 'child'}}
    </button>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Thank you. Yes, exactly what is happening in the directives and I need similar behavior with controllers only